# Images are not refreshed in Jframe

Tags: java, jframe

I am writing the code of showing images in Jframe in certain directory. The Jframe will show image one at a time.

My code showing that jframe's size changing but the image doesn't change. 
I put revalidate and paint but the images are not refreshed.

Here is updateFrame function which has logic of updating.

```
private void updateFrame(JFrame f, String billBoardImageFileLocation, int imageNumber) throws ClassNotFoundException, IOException {
    Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize(); //this is your screen size
    File folder = new File(billBoardImageFileLocation);
    String[] extensions = new String[]{"jpeg", "jpg"};
    List<File> imageFiles = (List<File>) FileUtils.listFiles(folder, extensions, false);
    ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(imageFiles.get(imageNumber % imageFiles.size()))); //imports the image

    if (isDebug.equals("Y")) {
        System.out.println("Files:" + imageFiles.get(imageNumber % imageFiles.size()).getAbsolutePath());
    }

    JLabel lbl = new JLabel(image); //puts the image into a jlabel\
            f.getContentPane().add(lbl); //puts label inside the jframe
    f.setSize(image.getIconWidth(), image.getIconHeight()); //gets h and w of image and sets jframe to the size
    f.getContentPane().revalidate();
    int x = (screenSize.width - f.getSize().width) / 2; //These two lines are the dimensions
    int y = (screenSize.height - f.getSize().height) / 2; //of the center of the screen
    f.setLocation(x, y); //sets the location of the jframe
    f.setVisible(true); //makes the jframe visible
    f.revalidate(); // **** added ****
    f.repaint();
    f.getContentPane().revalidate();
    f.getContentPane().repaint();
}
```

This is how I invoke the updateFrame function.

```
try
{
    pProcess = pb.start();
    if (showBillBoard.toUpperCase().equals("Y")) {
        ProcMon proMon = new ProcMon(pProcess);
        Thread t = new Thread(proMon);
        t.start();
        JFrame f = new JFrame(); //creates jframe f

        if (isDebug.equals("Y")) {
            System.out.println("Starting Thread");
        }
        int imageNumber = 0;

        while (!proMon.isComplete()) {
            updateFrame(f, billBoardImageFileLocation, imageNumber);
            Thread.sleep(Integer.parseInt(billBoardImageUpdateInterval)*1000);
            if (isDebug.equals("Y")) {
                System.out.println("Updating Framework");
            }
            imageNumber++;

        }
        f.dispose();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
JLabel lbl = new JLabel(image);
```

Don't create a new label, just update the icon of the existing label:

```
label.setIcon( image );
```

So change the method parameters to pass in the label as well as the frame.

That's all you need to do.

Answer (score 1):

You're doing long-running code on the Swing event thread, freezing it. Solution: don't. Swap your images using a Swing Timer, as this will allow repeated actions that don't step on the Swing event thread. Also never call `Thread.sleep` on this thread. For more on the EDT, the Swing event dispatch thread, please read [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/).